# AS3 Security SandBox Violation

Tags: actionscript-3, security, sandbox

I got this error message when trying to load a game from the browser:

```
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityDomain 'https://playerio.s3.amazonaws.com/competitions/ega2012/swf/Nhm-JFy6dEyuemmaE59BSQ.swf?AWSAccessKeyId=1Q3ETXSFA8S2F2TSA9R2&Expires=1361787227&Signature=TBCVKQDGlxthLj2YhoumxTxUGOo%3D' tried to access incompatible context 'http://cdn.playerio.com/rts-tvkyczvzk5uwqv8z12rw/Game2build29.swf'
SecurityError: Error #2121: Security sandbox violation: LoaderInfo.content: https://playerio.s3.amazonaws.com/competitions/ega2012/swf/Nhm-JFy6dEyuemmaE59BSQ.swf?AWSAccessKeyId=1Q3ETXSFA8S2F2TSA9R2&Expires=1361787227&Signature=TBCVKQDGlxthLj2YhoumxTxUGOo%3D cannot access http://cdn.playerio.com/rts-tvkyczvzk5uwqv8z12rw/Game2build29.swf. This may be worked around by calling Security.allowDomain.
   at flash.display::LoaderInfo/get content()
   at Loader3_fla::MainTimeline/onCompleteHandler()[Loader3_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:86]
```

It says you can workaround this error by using Security.allowDomain(), but I am not sure which domain to allow!

Answer (score 0):

You should put crossdomain.xml in your project folder, in which you can allow all domains or some specific domains from which your application is fetching data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

above is for all domains, if you want to allow some specific domains :

```
<allow-access-from domain="www.mysite.com" />
<allow-access-from domain="mysite.com" />
```

Comment: You've got this the wrong way around - the crossdomain file needs to be hosted wherever data is being requested from, outlining domains that are 'allowed' to pull data from it.

Comment: oh, sorry. yes he should put the XML file to that server(if it is accessible) not in his project folder. Thank you Marty to remind me my mistake.